# Let function inside if isn't working. (there is no error message)

Tags: javascript

Im making a snake game.
I got the problem that if the snake gets into the same position as the food the food respawns to a different place.

Nophing, I can't find the error anywhere in internet.

```
function draw (){

    if(snakeX == food.x && snakeY == food.y){
        score++;
        eat.play();
        let food = {
            x : Math.floor(Math.random()*17+1) * box,
            y : Math.floor(Math.random()*15+3) * box
        }
```

It is supposed to add a point to the score, make a sound, replace the food.

Now it is adding a point and making a sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), because you create a new local variable with a scope only in the block. Outside the variable keeps the same value without changing to the new value.

```
if (snakeX == food.x && snakeY == food.y) {
    score++;
    eat.play();
    food = {                                         // without let
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 17 + 1) * box,
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 15 + 3) * box
    };
}
```

Please have a look to this example:

`x` gets a new local scope with an own value. The outer variable `x` stays.

```js
let x = { a: 42 };

if (true) {
    let x = { b: 0 };
    console.log(x);   // b ...
}

console.log(x);       // a ...
```

Comment: Just a complement for the OP. As you can see in the code, `food.x` and `food.y` is already used. This menas `food` is already defined. And if you use `let food` you are creating a new variable called the same instead of updating the existing one. It's just a logical error, most painful ones.